# confirmation box containing data and images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i need confirmation message with url embed in list style and one image while closing tab/browser. In code it give confirmation message but not image and links. & i too don't how to show this. can anyone please help me.
Here is my code i want to do this, is it possible to do this in confirmation box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="../sum-of-textboxes.php" onclick="prevent()">Sum of textboxes.</a>
<ul id="listtype" style="display:none;">
   <li>abc</li>
   <li>xyz</li>
</ul>



<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {

        return 'Do you need help?';
       /*var list="<ul><li>"+ abc + "</li></ul>";
       var list=document.getElementById("listtype");
       return 'list';*/
    }
    function prevent() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () { };
    };
```

Comment: you have an extra curly brace, what is the prevent function supposed to do ?? where's the image ?

Comment: @Billy, see my updated code and image, i want to do in that way, is it possible to do this??

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can show only raw text message, without tags and style. Moreover, firefox shows only it's own default message ([HTML onbeforeunload Event Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp))

Comment: @sandysharma yes, you can put any url, though it'll not be a link.

Comment: ok @RBS, see my updated code and image, i want to do in that way, is it possible to do this??

Comment: @sandysharma You can try this code: `window.open(url, '_blank');return 'Your message';`, but most browsers may consider it as pop-up spam and block it.

Comment: i want to show multiple urls in box under message, not a single url.